# No vendor file on Symfony 2 using PhpStorm

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm for the Symfony project.

I've created new file in project type. I choose composer project and used `symfony/framework` to download `composer.phar`. After creating the project, I didn't find vendor file.

What am I doing wrong? Any tutorial to install Symfony in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is creating the project with the Symfony installer and without PhpStorm (like explained in the [symfony doc](http://symfony.com/download)).

Then, when it is correctly installed, open PhpStorm -> New Project from Existing Files -> locate your project folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am getting following erroors:
PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php on line 49
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\AMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php on line 49


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php on line 49

Comment: while running the program

Comment: @Anonymous Which program? This error tells that you are trying to execute PHPUnit tests (using PHPUnit v4.6 PHAR version?). I do not see how this error relates to your original question.

Comment: i mean while running the demo project why is it giving error in temp folder rather than projects location
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php on line 49

Comment: @Anonymous This most likely means  that you have created Run/Debug configuration of **wrong type**. The one which you are running is for PHPUnit tests. Regarding "temp" location -- it's all good. PHPUnit integration requires helper script for IDE integration purposes (track tests execution progress etc) which gets written in temp folder on each run and then gets deleted. The error tels that you either do not have PHPUnit on your system (or script cannot find it) or that you are using incompatible PHPUnit version.